# Add values to an array of a VBA object

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class

I'm starting to using classes in VBA and I can't understand why I can't add any value to the array called SDA in the object of the class that I've created.

The class module is:

```
'clsProject Class Module Code

Public LinhaProjeto As String
Public SDA As Variant



Public Sub Class_Initialize()

    ReDim SDA(1 To 12)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 12
        SDA(i) = 0
    Next i

End Sub
```

And the sub in a regular module is

```
Sub test()

    Dim oProject As clsProject
    Set oProject = New clsProject

    oProject.SDA(1) = 2
    Debug.Print oProject.SDA(1)
End Sub
```

The code runs without any errors, but it doesn't add the value as I thought it would. At the end of the sub called "test" the value of oProject.SDA(1) is still 0, and not 2 as I would like.

Can anyone help me find my mistake here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure ... but arrays aren't allowed as public members of classes (e.g. if you used "DIM SDA()" in the class it'll generate a compile error). I'll admit I may be completely wrong, but perhaps syntactically there's nothing wrong, but once you force the variant to be an array, then the main module code ignores it rather than generating a runtime error(?) Btw there's lots of other ways to implement what you're trying to do (e.g. private array in the class and wrap up the assignment in a property) so it shouldn't stop you from getting to your end goal. Cheers

Comment: @Techno Dabbler is right. A class can reference a public variable declared in a standard module but not the other way around. Declare `SDA()` as private and retrieve its value from outside the class using `Property Get`.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add this to your class:

```
Public Property Get ValSDA(Pos)
    ValSDA = SDA(Pos)
End Property

Public Property Let ValSDA(Pos, Nilai)
    SDA(Pos) = Nilai
End Property
```

and change your sub test like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim oProject As clsProject
    Set oProject = New clsProject

    oProject.ValSDA(1) = 2

    Debug.Print oProject.ValSDA(1)

End Sub
```